# Get alias name in result from mongoose query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to use alias names for crud operations. It only works well for create query. But for find and findOne I am using translateAliases in hooks. Main issue is for read query, for find and findOne result, the result does not contain alias name, but I need them.

This is my schema:

```
const someSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  f1: {
    type: Number, 
    default: -1,
    alias: 'field1'
  },
  f2: {
    type: Boolean, 
    default: false,
    alias: 'field2' 
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});`
```

If I am saving data with alias names, it is working, but for fetching/querying. I am using hooks:

```
`someSchema.pre('find', function() {
    this.model.translateAliases(this.getQuery());
});

someSchema.pre('findOne', function() {
  this.model.translateAliases(this.getQuery());
});
```

Now what I want is in result from these queries, the data should contain alias name.